# Unordered list items wont align in the center while using flexbox/flex direction column in a sidebar, also is there a better way to achieve this?

Tags: css, sidebar

**I am trying to align an image and a text under it in the center in an unordered list using display:flexbox, in a sidebar.**
however the image and the text are always displayed to the very left of the sidebar.i tried assign the flexbox to the "li" as well but that didn't change anything. 
also is there a better way to achieve this than using flexbox?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5% 95%;
  grid-template-rows: 5% 91% 4%;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header" "sidebar content" "footer footer";
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #4792e6;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: #4792e6;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #4792e6;
}

.img-circle {
  width: 70%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 15%;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: inherit;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(52, 73, 94, .44);
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.maintenance {
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 15% 85%;
  grid-template-areas: "maintenance-nav" "maintenance-info"
}

.maintenance-nav {
  grid-area: maintenance-nav;
  background-color: #ededed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.maintenance-info {
  grid-area: maintenance-info;
  background-color: blue;
}

.components {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 90%;
  grid-template-areas: "components-tree components-nav" "components-tree components-data";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.components-tree {
  grid-area: components-tree;
  background-color: white;
}

.components-nav {
  grid-area: components-nav;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.components-data {
  grid-area: components-data;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.maintenance-nav>div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 13%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
}

.components-nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.components-nav-links li a {
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.components-nav-links li a:hover {
  padding: 13px;
  border: 2px solid #4792e6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #419C99;
}

.sidebar-navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-navlist {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar-navitem img {
  width: 50%;
}

.sidebar-navitem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/custom.css') }}">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Layout grid -->
  <div class="grid">
    <!--header grid-->
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <!--sidebar grid-->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <nav class="sidebar-navbar">
        <ul class="sidebar-navlist">
          <li class="sidebar-navitem">
            <a href=""><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/maintenance.svg') }}"></a>
            <span>Main.</span>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-navitem">
            <a href=""><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/maintenance.svg') }}"></a>
            <span>Purchase</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <!--contenant grid-->
    <div class="content">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!--footer grid-->
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, try justify-content:center

Comment: I tried it, sadly didn't work.

Comment: Ok, try this .sidebar-navitem img { margin-left: 30%; display:flex;}

Comment: That did help thanks a lot, i am still not sure why align-items:center; not working tho.

Comment: Please try the code from answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a more good solution for the problem:

```
.sidebar-navitem {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
```

align-items:center was not working because it is required to set this property on a **li** not on **ul**.

If you apply this property to **ul**, the **li**s inside that are centered not the items inside **li**.